# How to implement == or >= operators for generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic type Foo which has a internal generic class Boo. Boo class a property Value of type K. In a method inside Foo i want to do a `boo.Value >= value` Note that second operand value is of type T. while compiling i am getting following error:

> Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

Can anyone please tell me whats the problem here?

Answer (score 4):

Restrict the type argument to `IComparable` , then you can implement the operations with the `CompareTo` method. Of course, you won't be able to use your generic class with every type, but I think every built-in type which can be compared using such operators like >, <=, ... implements this interface.

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi